# Angular: How to mock MatDialogRef while testing

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `DialogComponent` that has the following constructor where `Dialog` is a custom object:

```js
constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CustomDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Dialog
)
```

I created the following `TestBed` in Angular4:

```js
data = new Dialog()
data.message = 'Dialog Message'

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [MaterialModules],
    declarations: [CustomDialogComponent],
    providers: [MatDialogRef, { provide: Dialog, useValue: data }]
})

TestBed.overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
    set: {
        entryComponents: [CustomDialogComponent]
    }
})
await TestBed.compileComponents()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for MatDialogRef: (?, ?, ?).
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MatDialogRef: (?, ?, ?).
```

changing providers to:

```js
providers: [
    { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
    { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA,  useValue: data }
]
```

results in the following error:

```
Error: No provider for Dialog!
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: *Error: No provider for Dialog!* - why did you remove `{ provide: Dialog ...` ?

Comment: then it throws this error `Error: No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData!`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I solved it by changing the component constructor to:

```
constructor(
  public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CustomDialogComponent>,
  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Dialog | any
)
```

The providers in the TestBed were:

```
providers: [{ provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} }, { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: data }]
```

Comment: No reason why this would work. Please consider adding a reason if it did indeed do something. However, the order does not matter.

Comment: Because it is a types issue. Dialog is not of type MAT_DIALOG_DATA which is needed in providers for test. Hence, I had to allow data to take 'any' which then can accept MAT_DIALOG_DATA type also. Please read the question and the answer properly. Look at the inject statement.

Comment: How do I test multiple cases of data?

Comment: Found answer for swapping out provider value at test time: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/320#issuecomment-315866672

Answer (score 15):

If you use at least one `MatDialogRef` method, you should create a mock.
For example I use the `close()` method. Without it errors would be generated so I made the below class with an empty method.

```
export class MatDialogRefMock {
    close(value = '') {

    }
}
```

and use that instead of an empty value, with `useClass`

```
{ provide: MatDialogRef, useClass: MatDialogRefMock },
```

Comment: You can also provide a factory that generates a spyObj, so for each new test, you will have a fresh spy:

`{ provide: MatDialogRef, useFactory: () => jasmine.createSpyObj('MatDialogRef', ['close', 'afterClosed']) }`

Comment: That's the right answer!

Answer (score 12):

You can do this by the help of `jasmine` spy, as follow:

Step 1: Define the mock data

```
  const data = {
    title: 'title',
    message: 'message',
    summary: 'my summary'
  };
```

Step 2: Create jasmine spy for `MatDialogRef` (Write this inside `beforeEach` block)

```
const matDialogSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MatDialogRef', ['onNoClick', 'closeDialog']);
```

`onNoClick` and `closeDialog` are methods inside `MessagePopupComponnet`

Step 3: Configure the TestBed as follow:

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MatDialogRef,
      useValue: matDialogSpy
    },
    {
      provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
      useValue: data
    }
  ]
```

For the ref, I've provided the full code below:

```
import { DebugElement } from "@angular/core";
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from "@angular/material";

import { MessagePopupComponent } from "./message-popup.component";


describe('MessagePopup', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MessagePopupComponent>;
  let component: MessagePopupComponent;
  let el: DebugElement;
  let matDialogRef;

  const data = {
    title: 'title',
    message: 'message',
    summary: 'my summary'
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    const matDialogSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MatDialogRef', ['onNoClick', 'closeDialog']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MessagePopupComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MatDialogRef,
          useValue: matDialogSpy
        },
        {
          provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
          useValue: data
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents()
    .then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MessagePopupComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      el = fixture.debugElement;
      matDialogRef = TestBed.get(MatDialogRef);
    });

  }));

  fit('should create Message Popup component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy('Message popup not created')
  });

});
```

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: An absolute brilliant answer. Thx.

Answer (score 6):

Import MatDialogModule and MatDialogRef from angular/material/dialog instead of angular/material. Import the ModalDialogModule and provide providers for MatDialogRef in your TestBed.

```
Import {MatdialogModule,MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
declarations: [componentName],
imports: [MatdialogModule],
providers: [{provide : MatDialogRef, useValue : {}}]
});
```

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: i don't think , that the import is necessary

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, you can do the following steps:

1- You used the data as input to the dialog and used it in the constructor to set the variables. (in .ts)

```
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<any>,
          @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
     this.ip= data.ip;
     this.name= data.name;
  }
```

2- We should create fake data, (in .spec.ts)

```
const data = {
    ip: '1.1.1.1',
    name: 'test'
 }
```

3- We define provider as follows And we introduce data, (in .spec.ts)

```
 providers: [
   {provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {}},
   {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: data},
  ]
```

4- full code in .spec.ts

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {CustomDialogComponent} from './backup-list.component';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';
import {BrowserDynamicTestingModule} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import {NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';

const data = {
    ip: '1.1.1.1',
    name: 'test'
 };

describe('BackupListComponent', () => {
   let component: BackupListComponent;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<BackupListComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [CustomDialogComponent],
        imports: [
            TranslateModule.forRoot(),
            MatDialogModule,
            BrowserDynamicTestingModule
        ],
        providers: [
            {provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {}},
            {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: data},
        ],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
        .compileComponents();
  }));
 });
```