# Angular / Jasmine: No provider for Overlay! Also how to test a material dialog

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to test an angular material dialog, specifically, I want to test that it modifies the route when the dialog is closed. To that end, I don't want to mock/stub the dialog out (I don't think?), because I want it to run the actual .subscribe method that does the re-routing.

I'm getting two errors, on my actual dialog:

```
this.dialogRef.afterClosed is not a function
```

**login-dialog-component.spec.ts**

```
describe('LoginDialogComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginDialogComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginDialogComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LoginDialogComponent],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
        MatDialogModule
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: MatDialog},
        {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {}},
        {provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {}},
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginDialogComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The second error I'm getting is the test for the component that opens my dialog. It reports:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[MatDialog -> Overlay -> Overlay]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Overlay!
```

The test for component that opens my dialog: **login.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: MatDialog },
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {}}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The LoginComponent itself doesn't really require any testing, but as said above it's giving me the "No provider for overlay", presumably because the constructor is:

```
 constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog
  ) { }
```

LoginComponent then opens the LoginDialog.

The code I wish to test in LoginDialog is:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(_ =>
      this.router.navigate(['', {outlets: {login: null}}])
    );
  }
```

I want to ensure the router actually navigates away when the dialog closes.

So my question are

1. How do I pass in a real dialogRef to the constructor of LoginDialog?
2. How to get rid of the No provider for Overlay error?

Btw, if I change

```
{ provide: MatDialogRef, useValue {})
```

to:

```
{ provide: MatDialogRef }
```

(So I'm presumably trying to pass an actual MatDialogRef in)

The error changes from

```
this.dialogRef.afterClosed is not a function
```

to:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for MatDialogRef: (?, ?).
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

In `login-dialog-component.spec.ts`, remove the whole `providers` array because we shouldn't be mocking inner workings of `MatDialog` but keep `MatDialogModule` in the `imports`.

In `login.component.spec.ts`, add `MatDialogModule` in the `imports` array of `TestBed.configureTestingModule` and remove the `providers` array as mentioned previously.

Comment: 1) That gives me "No provider for MatDialogRef". I've found on https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8419#issuecomment-359698681 it seems MatDialogRef cannot be injected during tests, thus the solution is to use mocks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703365/angular-how-to-mock-matdialogref-while-testing Oh sorry about that, check out the last 2 answers there then.

Comment: 2) Thank you, that seems to have fixed the issue for the LoginComponent. I think to fix the other issue I'm going to have to just use a mock, I won't be able to test the router code if a real MatDialogRef can't be injected. I'll probably accept your answer. Thanks again.